# Creating a TabControl

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I am using Visual studio 2013 for my windows form application C#.
Is there any way to add a tab control programmatically? If user have admin rights, then there is new tabcontrol for admin. Otherwise there is no admin tabcontrol. How I can do this?
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: _tabcontrol_ vs _regular tabcontrols_ Could you explain what is the difference?

Comment: I want to say that if user logged in as admin then there is a tabcontrol for admin. And if user logged in as a regular user then there is  no admin tabcontrol.@Steve

Comment: Are you asking basically how to add `System.Windows.Forms.TabControl` to your Form programmatically?

Comment: You want an entire `TabControl`?...or just a new `Tab` in an existing TabControl?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a quick example of creating a TabControl and adding a Tab to it called "Admin":

```
        TabControl TC = new TabControl();
        // ... setup the TabControl ...
        TC.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        panel1.Controls.Add(TC); // add the TabControl to some kind of container

        TabPage admin = new TabPage("Admin");
        // ... add controls to the "admin" TabPage ...
        TC.TabPages.Add(admin); // add the TabPage to our TabControl
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, create new WinForms project in VS, place `TabControl` “manually” in your window. Open `Form1.Designer.cs` file and you will see how it’s done programmatically.

this part:

```
        // 

        // tabControl1

        // 

        this.tabControl1.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill;

        this.tabControl1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 0);

        this.tabControl1.Name = "tabControl1";

        this.tabControl1.SelectedIndex = 0;

        this.tabControl1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(1694, 1091);

        this.tabControl1.TabIndex = 1;

        // 

        // tabPage1

        // 

        this.tabPage1.Controls.Add(this.webControl1);

        this.tabPage1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(4, 34);

        this.tabPage1.Name = "tabPage1";

        this.tabPage1.Padding = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(3);

        this.tabPage1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(1686, 1053);

        this.tabPage1.TabIndex = 0;

        this.tabPage1.Text = "tabPage1";

        this.tabPage1.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
```

Of course, You don't have to add this control in `InitializeComponent();` method. You can manipulate your UI everywhere